# Partial differentiation with respect to an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the differentiation problem as follows:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \ell(s)} \int^\rho_0 (as+b) \ell(s)ds 
$$

There is a similar textbook model that solves

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \ell(s)} \int^\rho_0 \ell(s)^\alpha ds = \alpha \ell(s)^{\alpha-1}  \quad \text{for each s}
$$

The main point is that the textbook model solves the first derivative for each $s$.
Similarly, I would like to solve my problem for each $s$ and I think the answer would be $(as+b)$. However, I am not confident with my answer so I would like to know the opinion of the others. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the meaning of $\frac{\partial }{{\partial \ell (s)}}$? Note that the function you are "differentiating" is a function of $\rho$ and not $s$, $s$ is the integration variable.

Comment: As @Gary points out, [you really need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) $\delta$, not $\partial$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It is an optimization problem, and it is a part of solving for the first-order condition with respect to $\ell(s)$.